# Why was my question closed as "not a real question"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

On what ground is this question "not real"? Someone please explain it here, thanks.

[How should one retrieve the word under cursor, of current active window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523465/how-should-one-retrieve-the-word-under-cursor-of-current-active-window)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question lacks two things:

1. **Context**. Why are you trying to do this?
2. **Effort**. What have you tried? What's not working with what you've tried?

We generally expect users put effort into their questions. Stack Overflow is not a place where you can get people to magically solve your problems without effort on your part.

**The more effort you put in, the more effort people will put in to answer your question.**

Edit: After hearing out Kev, my thought on the question has changed *slightly*.

The question still lacks both those things I brought up before, but it does have the luxury of being **interesting** (or complicated, depending on your point of view): That is, what you're trying isn't easy to do, and the problem space isn't well explored.

With that in mind, this question is *borderline*.  However, given your history of asking a lot of questions (and they aren't all gems), I can see why the community voted to close your question.  If you had asked fewer questions, or didn't have a history of borderline/closed questions, then it's likely this question wouldn't have been closed.

For the record, after hearing Kev out, I agree with him that this question should be re-opened.